# I would like to know how to run a vba script to find and replace multiple words in only one sheet not the whole workgroup?

Tags: vba

I have found a vba script to find and replace words but the script replaces the words in the whole workbook, I would like it to replace the words only in a specific sheet. This is the code I have found.

```
Sub Multi_FindReplace()
'PURPOSE: Find & Replace a list of text/values throughout entire workbook
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

fndList = Array("United States", "New York")
rplcList = Array("US", "NY")

'Loop through each item in Array lists
  For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook
      For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Cells.Replace what:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
      Next sht

  Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the sheet loop and specify the sheet name in the code where it says "Sheet1".

```
Sub Multi_FindReplace()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

fndList = Array("United States", "New York")
rplcList = Array("US", "NY")
Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")   'this is the relevant worksheet    
For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
   sht.Cells.Replace what:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Next x

End Sub
```